# Even after renderResponse set in the beforePhase of the InvokeApplication PhaseListener - events are still broadcasted in myfaces

Tags: jsf-2.2, myfaces, omnifaces, mojarra

We are using myfaces on websphere liberty profile server.

We have a phaseListener that is setup against InvokeApplication phase - so when there is a exception in beforePhase, we set the renderResponse on facesContext, thinking that it will skip further processing and will not broadcast the events on InvokeApplication, but it does.

LifecycleImpl.java - line # 191 onwards –

```
        if (shouldRenderResponse(context, currentPhaseId, true))
        {
            skipFurtherProcessing = true;
        }

        if (executor.execute(context))
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Now the above code clearly doesn't skip the executor.execute(context) even when renderResponse was executed.
But Mojarra 2.2.11 - behaves differently - it will skip if renderResponse is called in beforePhase.
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase - line # 99 onwards:

Phase.java

```
       handleBeforePhase(context, listeners, event);
        if (!shouldSkip(context)) {
            execute(context);
        }
```

"shouldSkip" method impl in Phase.java

```
   private boolean shouldSkip(FacesContext context) {
    if (context.getResponseComplete()) {
        return (true);
    } else if (context.getRenderResponse() &&
               !PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE.equals(this.getId())) {
        return (true);
    } else {
        return (false);
    }
    }
```

Now either Mojarra is wrong or Myfaces implementation is wrong. In our case (ie myfaces implementation), what should be the mechanism to skip the events if render response is set on the before phase in INVOKE APPLICATION .